# DiagramWebControl & PaletteGroupBar on IIS 7.5

Tags: syncfusion

im trying to deploy my web site on IIS 7.5, its working well but both DiagramWebControl & PaletteGroupBar are not working.
This is my Web.config. i dont know is there is something missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="KBDConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
      Integrated Security=SSPI; database=KBD.mdf;
      AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|KBD.mdf; User Instance=true"  
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
    <add path="ImgRequest.ashx" verb="*" 
 type="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Diagram.NodeRenderHandler,Syncfusion.Diagram.Web, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
  <add path="PaletteImgRequest.ashx" verb="*" type="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Diagram.ThumbNodeRenderHandler,Syncfusion.Diagram.Web, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
  <!--<add path="OverviewImgRequest.ashx" verb="*" type="Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Diagram.OverviewDocumentRenderHandler,Syncfusion.Diagram.Web, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"/>-->
</httpHandlers>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Tools.Web, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Shared.Web, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Core, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=632609B4D040F6B4" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Shared.Base, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Grid.Base, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Tools.Base, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Diagram.Web, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Diagram.Base, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Diagram.Windows, Version=10.402.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Compression.Base, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.Pdf.Base, Version=10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="KBDSqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="KBDSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="KBDConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="KrallmannBusinessDesigner" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="KBDSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="KBDSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="KBDConnectionString" applicationName="KrallmannBusinessDesigner" />
  </providers>
  <!--<properties>
    <add name="UserName" type="String"/>
    <add name="Email" type="String" />
  </properties>-->
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="Account/Login.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
 </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please add the diagram handlers under the system.webServer’s “handlers” section in web.config file in order to resolve the reported issue.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name='ImgRequest' path='ImgRequest.ashx' verb='*' type='Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Diagram.NodeRenderHandler,Syncfusion.Diagram.Web, Version= 10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89' />
<add name='PaletteImgRequest' path='PaletteImgRequest.ashx' verb='*' type='Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Diagram.ThumbNodeRenderHandler,Syncfusion.Diagram.Web, Version= 10.404.0.71, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89' />   
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Refer the diagram sample browser application and it’s web.config file in the below location.
...\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\10.4.0.71\Web\Diagram.Web\Samples\3.5